# Arcgis Pro model builder collect values give same value for each iterate

Tags: arcgis

disclaimer, pardon my english. its not my first language.

so i have list of polygon to iterate with model builder. the *OFM* will be clipped with each of iterated polygon. the goals is to collect the value of mean_totalkilometers from the Lines child element. i tried it multiple times but the table from collected value always give me same value with correct record count.

[#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQLbl.png)
[#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUxhf.png)

First with A* wildcard, collected value return 6 record which is correct. but all the values are the same for each record iterate.

it happens to B* wildcard and soon. Collect Value keep return same value for all the records

I wonder whats wrong with my model? Thank you!